# React function await not working. Executing at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am uploading products into database.
I have a submit function:

```
 const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      await uploadImage()
 
      //this executes at the same time as the above function
      window.location.reload()

    } catch (error) {
      alert(error)
    }
  }
```

Everything under uploadImage doesn't wait for it to finish

this uploadImage function takes the image and uploads it to cloudinary like this:

```
  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const data = new FormData()
    if (formImage) {
      data.append("file", formImage)
      data.append("upload_preset", "***-")
      data.append("cloud_name", "***")
      try {
        const resp = await fetch("***", {
          method: "post",
          body: data
        })
        const dataJson = await resp.json()
        setUrl(dataJson.secure_url);

//I  had insertProduct Function under the other one on submit but they executed at the same time so it didn't work

        insertProduct(producto, dataJson.secure_url)
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
```

I have these two functions inside the same file.

↓↓↓↓ This is my inserProduct function ↓↓↓↓

Now this insertProduct function I have it in a .js file outside /pages

```
import { collection, query, where, addDoc, getDoc, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../config/firebase";

export const insertProduct = async (prodData, image) => {
  const {
    nombre, precioOferta, precioRegular,
    cantStock, sku,
    breveDescripcion, visible,
    envioGratis, coincideMedidas,
    descripcion, picture,
    etiquetas, vendor,
    available_colors, available_sizes
  } = prodData

  const tags = etiquetas.split(" ")
  if (image) {
    try {
      const uploadedProduct = await addDoc(collection(db, "products"), {
        name: nombre,
        price: precioOferta,
        regular_price: precioRegular,
        vendor: {
          vendor_id: vendor.vendor_id
        },
        sku,
        freeShipping: envioGratis,
        stock_quantity: cantStock,
        is_published: visible,
        short_description: breveDescripcion,
        description: descripcion,
        picture: image,
        tags,
        available_sizes,
        available_colors
      })
      return uploadedProduct
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }else{
    console.log('no hay imagen')
  }
}
```

And this is what this function does.

My problem is with the onSubmit function which the code under the function is inmediately executing when the above function is called.

I hope you can help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to put `await` in front of `insertProduct`

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a use of `Promise.all()` as it's described in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).
Smth like this

```
await Promise.all(
      await uploadImage()
      await window.location.reload()
    )
```